# JS Array image links are failing to load but will load when written as HTML. How to make these links work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, google-chrome

I've been trying to create a grid of randomly appearing and disappearing images via an array for a class, art project. In google chrome, I've been able to load image icons so I'm sure that the code works except for the images loading. These images can load but they won't specifically in the Javascript. Is there any surefire way to link them and have them appear on the site?

I've tried to change the link in "const images = imageSources.map" and I've also tried changing the link in the HTML head but to no avail. Is there a more direct way to include my links? Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Website For 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="website-for-one.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Website_for_One/Images/image1.jpg">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Website_for_One/Images/image2.jpg">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Website_for_One/Images/image3.jpg">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Website_for_One/Images/image4.jpg">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Website_for_One/Images/image5.jpg">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Website_for_One/Images/image6.jpg">








  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="image-container"></div>
    <div id="container">
      <p id="three">Three Words Against The World</p>
      <p id="title">A Website For One</p>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>

    <div id="message-container">
      <span id="message"></span>
    </div>

 <div id="image-load">
      <img src="image1.jpg">
      <img src="image2.jpg">
      <img src="image3.jpg">
      <img src="image4.jpg">
      <img src="image5.jpg">
      <img src="image6.jpg">
      <img src="image7.jpg">
      <img src="image8.jpg">
      <img src="image9.jpg">
      <img src="image10.jpg">
  </div>

<script src="web_for_one.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      const imageSources = [
        'image1.jpg',
        'image2.jpg',
        'image3.jpg',
        'image4.jpg',
        'image5.jpg',
        'image6.jpg',
        'image7.jpg',
        'image8.jpg',
        'image9.jpg',
        'image10.jpg',
      ];

      const images = imageSources.map(source => 'Website_for_One/Images/' + source);

      const container = document.getElementById('image-container');

      for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = images[i];
        img.style.position = 'absolute';
        img.style.top = Math.random() * window.innerHeight + 'px';
        img.style.left = Math.random() * window.innerWidth + 'px';
        container.appendChild(img);
      }

      setInterval(() => {
        const imgs = container.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
          imgs[i].style.top = Math.random() * window.innerHeight + 'px';
          imgs[i].style.left = Math.random() * window.innerWidth + 'px';
        }
      }, 5000);

      setInterval(() => {
        const imgs = container.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
          imgs[i].src = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
        }
      }, 10000);
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
    grid-template-rows: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
}

#image-load{
  opacity: 0%;
  display: none;
}

#three{
    font-size: .7vw; 
      grid-column: 1 / 6;
      grid-row: 1;
}

#title{
    font-size: .7vw; 
      grid-column: 3 / 6;
      grid-row: 1;
}

#words{
    font-size: .7vw; 
    grid-column: 1 / 6;
    grid-row: 4;
}

#message-container{
border: 1px solid red;  
}

#message{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: .7vw; 
}

#imagegrid {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#imagegrid img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: move;
}
```

Here's my JS:

```
const messages = ["I Love You", "Nothing to prove", "Nothing to hide", "Nothing to lose", "okay, pure", "a dream is more powerful", "Mom says hello", "How are you?", "I miss you", "Listen", "You're beautiful", "Four words against the world: I love you _____"]; // Define an array of messages
const fonts = ["Arial, sans-serif", "Helvetica, sans-serif", "Verdana, sans-serif"]; // Define an array of fonts
const messageContainer = document.getElementById("message-container"); // Get the message container element
const messageElement = document.getElementById("message"); // Get the message element
let messageIndex = 0; // Set the initial message index

function displayNextMessage() {
  messageIndex = (messageIndex + 1) % messages.length; // Increment the message index and wrap around to 0 when it reaches the end
  messageElement.textContent = messages[messageIndex]; // Set the message text to the next message
  messageElement.style.opacity = 1; // Set the message opacity to 1 to fade it in
  messageElement.style.fontFamily = fonts[Math.floor(Math.random() * fonts.length)]; // Set the font family to a random font from the fonts array
  setTimeout(hideMessage, 2000); // Call the hideMessage function after 2 seconds
}

function hideMessage() {
  messageElement.style.opacity = 0; // Set the message opacity to 0 to fade it out
  setTimeout(displayNextMessage, 500); // Call the displayNextMessage function after 0.5 seconds to show the next message
}

displayNextMessage(); // Call the displayNextMessage function to start the animation
```

Comment: It’s just a hunch, but is that really the image sources’ path? The path is relative to the html file, so you ought not specify the parent folder. If you prefer to use the absolute path, `/Website_for_One/Images/` might be the correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're doing well.

The problem rises when you try to add for example `image1.jpg` as the `src` for the img tag. The absolute paths don't work in this case. You should consider adding the full path of the image (e.g. `https://yourwebsite.com/Images/image1.jpg`) to the `src` attribute. How you do that, depends on your usecase. But I believe you can add them like this for example:

```js
imgs[i].src = `https://yourwebsite.com/Images/${images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]}`;
```

Or if you prefer a more general way to do that:

```js
imgs[i].src = `${window.location.origin}/Images/${images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]}`;
```